# How to add two unique validation for one input

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.8, laravel-validation

I'm trying to validate an input like this:

```
$validatedPhone = $request->validate([
        'user_input' => 'required|unique:users,user_name|regex:/^09\d{9}$/|max:11|min:11',
]
```

Now I need to say that the value of this input does not exist at another table which is `members` table and `member_mobile` column.

But I have already defined a `unique` rule for the users table with `user_name` column.

So how to define two unique rules for two different tables for validating one input?

Comment: Can't you just add another unique rule? `unique:users,user_name|unique:mobile....`

Comment: @M.Eriksson Yes I just tested it and it seems working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another rule as shown below

```
 $validatedPhone = $request->validate([
        'user_input' => 'required|unique:users,user_name|unique:members,member_mobile|regex:/^09\d{9}$/|max:11|min:11',
    ]
```